# Not being able to find my mapping anymore (spring - controller)

Tags: spring, configuration, controller

I am not being able to find my mapping anymore (I made it work. But then, I made changes, but probably due to cache, I didn't realize when it stopped working :-( ). It gives 404 error now when I click on submit on the form. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

JSP:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/app/app/studentSearchById" commandName="student">
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
// @RequestMapping("/studentSearch")
public class StudentSearchController {

    // @Autowired
    //StudentService userService = new StudentService();

    // @RequestMapping(value="/StudentSearchById", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    // public ModelAndView searchById(@PathVariable Long studentId) {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/studentSearchById", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView searchById(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student, Map<String, Object> map,
            HttpServletRequest request) {

        StudentService userService = new StudentService();
        Student studentFound = userService.findStudent(student.getStudentId());

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        // modelAndView.addObject("students", studentFound);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: Your form points to `/tar/studentSearchById`. Your mapping is for `/studentSearchById`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using stereotype annotation (@Controller , @Service, @Repository) then its better to use context: component-scan tag to say that Spring has to scan packages searching the annotation and register beans within the application context.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alok. I never used that tag and I am really confused with that. I suppose some stereotype annotation is missing, once my app is not being able to inject the dependencies... I just posted other question related to that, after hours struggling to try to solve it...I saw you already commented on that, thanks a lot for your help twice just today! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours on this... just after posting, I figured out...

I had changed the line on my spring-servlet.xml. Putting the line as before, it worked:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.controller.package" />
```